# Appending nodes alphabetically to create linked list. Can't get nodes to link (C program)

Tags: c, loops, linked-list

> I have problem with this section of my code for, some reason everything seems to work fine but when I print out the whole linked list it only prints the header and next node if it went through "if (compare_node(list, node) == -1)" function. I have written that rest = list, but operations I do on rest doesn't seem to affect the list variable. I need help on how to link the output of rest variables to list variable which is the header of my code.

```
link *add_node(link *list, link *node) { //  list = header, node =  new node I want to insert alphabetically
    link* temp;
    link* rest;
    rest = list;

    if (compare_node(list, node) == -1){
        temp = list;
        list = node;
        list->next = temp;
        printf("%s->%s->%s...\n",list->node_str, list->next->node_str, list->next->next->node_str);
        printf("nodes interchanged\n");
    }
    else{
        while(rest != NULL){
            if(compare_node(rest, node) == -1){
                printf("initial rest value: %s\n", rest->node_str);
                temp = rest;
                rest = node;
                rest->next = temp;
                printf("nodes interchanged, new rest value: %s\n", rest->node_str); //nodes interchanged: name
                printf("%s->%s->%s...\n",list->node_str, list->next->node_str, list->next->next->node_str);
                return list;
            }
            rest = rest->next;
            printf("next rest value: %s\n", rest->node_str); //next rest value: name
        }
        rest = node;
        printf("new rest value %s\n", rest->node_str);
    }
    return list;
}
```

> my output looks like this:
> Enter the user name for user N1: mike
> Enter the user name for user N2: ann
> ann->mike->(null)...
> nodes interchanged
> Enter the user name for user N3: luka
> next rest value: mike
> initial rest value: mike
> nodes interchanged, new rest value: luka
> ann->mike->(null)...
> Enter the user name for user N4: nick
> next rest value: mike
> next rest value: (null)
> new rest value nick
> Enter the user name for user N5:
>  1. ann
>  2. mike
> My whole Code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STR_LEN 80

//STRUCT
typedef struct link_node
{
char node_str[MAX_STR_LEN];
struct link_node *next;
} link;

void Node_Create(link *Node, char* userName, link *nextNode);
int compare_node(link *n1, link *n2);
link *add_node(link *list, link *node);
void display_list(link *head);

//MAIN
int main() {
    int num, i = 1;
    char name[MAX_STR_LEN];
    link *Curr, *Head;

    printf("Enter the user name for user N%d: ", i);
    gets(name);
    Head = (link*)malloc(sizeof(link));
    Node_Create(Head, name, NULL);
    i++;

    while(1){
        printf("Enter the user name for user N%d: ", i);
        gets(name);
        if (strcmp(name, "\0") == 0) break;
        Curr = (link*)malloc(sizeof(link));
        Node_Create(Curr, name, NULL);
        Head = add_node(Head, Curr);
        i++;
    }

    display_list(Head);
    printf("\n%s\n", Head->node_str);

    return 0;
}

//FUNCTION FOR CREATING NODES
void Node_Create(link *Node, char* userName, link *nextNode) {
    strcpy(Node->node_str, userName);
    Node->next = nextNode;
}

//FUNCTION FOR COMPARING NODES
int compare_node(link *n1, link *n2) {
    link* Temp;

    if(n1->node_str[0] > n2->node_str[0])
        return -1;
    else if(n1->node_str[0] == n2->node_str[0])
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

//FUNCTION FOR ADDING NODES
link *add_node(link *list, link *node) { //  list = header, node =  new node I want to insert alphabetically
    link* temp;
    link* rest;
    rest = list;

    if (compare_node(list, node) == -1){
        temp = list;
        list = node;
        list->next = temp;
        printf("%s->%s->%s...\n",list->node_str, list->next->node_str, list->next->next->node_str);
        printf("nodes interchanged\n");
    }
    else{
        while(rest != NULL){
            if(compare_node(rest, node) == -1){
                printf("initial rest value: %s\n", rest->node_str);
                temp = rest;
                rest = node;
                rest->next = temp;
                printf("nodes interchanged, new rest value: %s\n", rest->node_str); //nodes interchanged: name
                printf("%s->%s->%s...\n",list->node_str, list->next->node_str, list->next->next->node_str);
                return list;
            }
            rest = rest->next;
            printf("next rest value: %s\n", rest->node_str); //next rest value: name
        }
        rest = node;
        printf("new rest value %s\n", rest->node_str);
    }
    return list;
}

//FUNCTION FOR DISPLAYING NODES
void display_list(link *head) {
    link *rest = head;
    int i = 1;

    while(rest != NULL){
        printf("%d. %s\n", i++, rest->node_str);
        rest = rest->next;
    }
}
```

> Thanks in advance :)

Comment: regarding: `gets(name);`  The function:  `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the C language about a decade ago.  Strongly suggest using `fgets()` (which does have a different parameter list than `gets()`)

Comment: See `addinorder()` within [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB). For strings, you would replace `while (ps && ps->data <= pn->data)` with `while (ps && strcmp (ps->data, pn->data) < 0)`. More importantly see [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102). Use `fgets (name, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin)` instead and trim the `'\n'` from the end with `name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: thanks  I will do that but I don't think that's the reason it doesn't wok. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: regarding the function: `compare_node()`  is this to try and produce a sorted list?

Comment: Or probably better (but dynamically allocating for the string) is [Singly Linked List of Strings With Sorted Insertion](https://pastebin.com/PechfyQa) See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/) for details on iterating using both the *address of the pointer* and pointer -- which makes list insertions and deletions much simpler.

Comment: will do that. thanks @user3629249

Comment: no compare_node() is to return integer values by comparing the first letter of each name(for example, if first node has "bigger" first character than second node it will return  -1). sorted list should be produced in add_node(). @user3629249

Comment: Yes, that will work too, it just means the sort of two strings with the same first character won't be strictly sorted. From an efficiency standpoint, calling `strcmp()` does essentially the same thing and stops when it reaches the first character that differs -- or end of string, so the first-char trick doesn't do much from an optimization standpoint.

Comment: the posted code results in a massive memory leak.  Before exiting the program, pass each of the allocated (via `malloc()`) memory segments to `free()`.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `Head = (link*)malloc(sizeof(link));`  The function: `malloc()` can fail.  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.. If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` which will output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: thank you very much, I just started learning structs and linked lists and your comments are very helpful. @user3629249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the previous node you must keep a pointer to it. As an example, you can do it this way :

```
    link * prev = NULL; 
    while(rest != NULL){
        if(compare_node(rest, node) == -1){
            temp = rest;
            rest = node;
            rest->next = temp;
            if (prev) prev->next = rest; //<==== Sets the next of previous
            return list;
        }
        prev = rest; // <=== Stores previous
        rest = rest->next;
        printf("next rest value: %s\n", rest->node_str); //next rest value: name
    }
    rest = node;
    printf("new rest value %s\n", rest->node_str);
```

When the head is changed you don't need that since, by definition, there is no node before head.

Comment: Thank you man this explains it. I was struggling with my code for so long and I think you just resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

First 2 remarks. As you have already been told in comments, do not use `gets`, and use `strcmp` to compare strings (you version only compare the first character of both strings).

Now for the actual problem:

To insert a node in a linked list, you must change the link of the previous node. Let's say we have in lexicographic order B < X < C and the list  is A -> B -> C -> D. You tests will say:

- X > A: try next
- X > B: try next
- x < C: ok insert

But you have to do:

```
B->next = X;
X->next = C;
```

It is useless to change the value of any other variable, that means that you have to record the previous node.

Comment: Thanks for the explaining, but I'd like to know, how can I record the previous node? especially in the case where the head variable is replaced?

Comment: also, rest is initialized with "list". I have "rest = list;" written right after "link* rest;"